# Which filter is faster to search all User in LDAP?

Tags: c#, active-directory, indexing, ldap

I have this:

> (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))

And this:

> (&(objectCategory=user)(samaccountname=*))

Which one will be faster?  I am not so familiar with Active Directory architecture...

Comment: @Default I wrote a small program with using Stopwatch to measure both calls in ticks, but sometime they are the same speed, sometime one is faster, but sometime is not... So the result is not so accurate....

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server. If `objectCategory` has an equality index and `objectClass` has an equality index *and* `samAccountName` has a `present` index, then the number of entries returned and the number of bytes per entry (as dictated by the requested attributes) will count towards the cost of fulfilling the search.

Comment: hmm I am little confuse....  So first filter requires objectCategory and objectClass has index.  2nd filter requires objectCategory and  samAccountName has index.  if both filters has indexes they needed, which ones is faster?  Both should returns same amount of bytes per entry and both should return same number of entries right?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there are a lot of server conditions that can play into the results as far as performance.

Also depends on what type of entries you wish to return.
As you are using Active Directory you should try one of these:

All users:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

or (We usually see this as faster)

```
(sAMAccountType=805306368)
```

All contacts:

```
(objectClass=contact)
```

All users and contacts:

```
(objectClass=user)
```

-jim

Comment: objectClass isn't index, so all users and contacts would be (objectCategory=person)